# Paypal checkout - order capture get PERMISSION-DEINED from server but works in javascript client

Tags: php, sdk, paypal-sandbox, checkout

I am working Paypal checkout php sdk. I follow the document from here https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

First I create an order

```php
$env = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $secretKey);

$client = new PayPalHttpClient($env);

$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();

$request->prefer('return=representation');

$request->body = buildOrder($order);

//buildOrder has this param:
/*
"application_context" => [
     "return_url" => 'domain/paypal/return.php',
     "cancel_url" => 'domain/paypal/cancel.php'
 ]
*/

//request body
$body = array (
  'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
  'purchase_units' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'reference_id' => 9,
      'amount' => 
      array (
        'value' => 125.63,
        'currency_code' => 'USD',
        'breakdown' => 
        array (
          'item_total' => 
          array (
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 125.63,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'items' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'name' => 'Demo 46',
          'description' => NULL,
          'sku' => NULL,
          'unit_amount' => 
          array (
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 98.0,
          ),
          'quantity' => '1',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'name' => 'Demo 28',
          'description' => NULL,
          'sku' => NULL,
          'unit_amount' => 
          array (
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 12.22,
          ),
          'quantity' => '1',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'name' => 'Addon 33',
          'description' => NULL,
          'sku' => NULL,
          'unit_amount' => 
          array (
            'currency_code' => 'USD',
            'value' => 15.41,
          ),
          'quantity' => '1',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'application_context' => 
  array (
    'return_url' => 'http://domain.test/paypal/return',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://domain.test/paypal/canceled',
  ),
)
$response = $client->execute($request);
```

Create Order response:

```
{"statusCode":201,"result":{"id":"10M47599SM3059709","intent":"CAPTURE","status":"CREATED","purchase_units":[{"reference_id":"9","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"125.63","breakdown":{"item_total":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"125.63"}}},"payee":{"email_address":"sb-kpo1v7959755@business.example.com","merchant_id":"XEH8BEAE3FXPW"},"items":[{"name":"Demo 46","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"98.00"},"quantity":"1"},{"name":"Demo 28","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"12.22"},"quantity":"1"},{"name":"Addon 33","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"15.41"},"quantity":"1"}]}],"create_time":"2021-09-30T22:59:31Z","links":[{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/10M47599SM3059709","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/checkoutnow?token=10M47599SM3059709","rel":"approve","method":"GET"},{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/10M47599SM3059709","rel":"update","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v2\/checkout\/orders\/10M47599SM3059709\/capture","rel":"capture","method":"POST"}]},"headers":{"":"","Content-Type":"application\/json","Content-Length":"1085","Connection":"keep-alive","Date":"Thu, 30 Sep 2021 22","Application_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","Cache-Control":"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Caller_acct_num":"XEH8BEAE3FXPW","Paypal-Debug-Id":"95be3b11c12e7","Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"}}
```

Then I can get orderID, I store it in session. Next I redirect buyer to `approve` url from Paypal response.
[image]

Next, buyer makes payment and Paypal drives buyer to my return url above.

In return.php I capture order by this piece of code

```php
$env = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $secretKey);

$client = new PayPalHttpClient($env);

//$orderId can get from session or from `token` param in return url
$request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);

$request->prefer('return=representation');


$response = $client->execute($request);
```

New response from OrdersCaptureRequest:

```
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."}],"message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"e8021203038f1","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED","rel":"information_link"}]} {"exception":"[object] (PayPalHttp\\HttpException(code: 0): {\"name\":\"NOT_AUTHORIZED\",\"details\":[{\"issue\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"description\":\"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource.\"}],\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.\",\"debug_id\":\"e8021203038f1\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"rel\":\"information_link\"}]}
```

The response I have is (old):

```
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."}],"message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"ff1bfd34831cb","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED","rel":"information_link"}]} {"exception":"[object] (PayPalHttp\\HttpException(code: 0): {\"name\":\"NOT_AUTHORIZED\",\"details\":[{\"issue\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"description\":\"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource.\"}],\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.\",\"debug_id\":\"ff1bfd34831cb\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"rel\":\"information_link\"}]}
```

Then I came with solution to combine between client and server

1. I embed the Paypal checkout button
2. Create order from server
3. Handle approval from js client
4. Capture order by Paypal js function.
   And Paypal responses with `COMPLETED` status.

```js
<script
            src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID]"></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions){
                return fetch('create-order.php', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                }).then(function(res) {

                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(data) {

                    return data.token;
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions){
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details){
                   console.log(details);
                });
            }
});
</script>
```

Even I tried to send orderID from `onApprove` event of Paypal js to my server for capturing order, the same issue with `PERMISSION-DENIED` happens.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting away to a rel:approve URL is for old websites. You should use the PayPal button rather than redirecting away, it's a much nicer and more modern in-context experience for the buyer, keeping your site loaded in the background/lightbox fade.

The problem you are having with capturing an order on the server side appears to be a matter of using the wrong request object:

```
//$orderId can get from session or from `token` param in return url
$request = new OrdersCreateRequest($orderId);
```

At this stage, you need an **OrdersCaptureRequest** instead. See the sample [bundled as part of the SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK/blob/develop/samples/CaptureIntentExamples/CaptureOrder.php#L23).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used Paypal button but I want to capture order from server instead of Paypal javascript. For the OrdersCreateRequest, it was my mistake of copy-paste. In fact I used OrdersCaptureRequest, edited my question.

Comment: (1) Create a new sandbox Business account in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts
(2) Create a new REST app for that account in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: (3) Use the new APP's Client ID and Secret everywhere, including in your API calls and for the JS SDK.  If the problem persists, log your complete orders Create and orders Capture API calls -- including the request and response text -- and update your question with this information, along with the new sandbox Client ID and secret credentials you are using.

Comment: I created new business account, created new app for that business account. I edited the question with more details. Thanks @Preston

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in your edits, but you didn't include the Sandbox client-id and secret you are using, so it can't be tested to reproduce.  The next thing you should try is a newly-created Personal account from https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts to ensure the buyer account is ok

Comment: Sorry for being late as SO was under maintenance. Here is my sandbox criteria:
 
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID="Ab2ritryLBG9LHeqkmhQb9OdFaTsUQ8Spkgk4bwLrfFCbNhixxeOmwVbMCL5QA60wBgwzmjesTETC9zr"
PAYPAL_SECRET_KEY="ECeUWXDhc_3ZxoFrdilC0z3tka5KXFoDQcO7vq4R_M6Bhft5OuvQqBw04BXJ4ifhqCpWE9QJ5xpgnJMK"

for testing you can use this buyer account:
sb-n4hkc7961966@personal.example.com / Od6B^V=n

Comment: Those credentials all work fine and result in successfully captured transactions.

Comment: did you capture it from server end or using Paypal js?

Comment: From the server. Should always be the same as where the order was created.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same situation and the problem was my access token.
Generating an access token via /v1/oauth2/token
and passing the
Request Header `"Authorization", "Basic " & Base64(clientID) & ":" & Base64(clientSecret)`
Works and returns an access token.
But this token will only allow you to Create an Order not Capture it!

**You need to Base64 encode the ":" as well!**
Changing the request header to
`"Authorization", "Basic " & Base64(clientID & ":" & clientSecret)`
Creates a token that will allows capture as well.

This took me ages to debug as the token was returning and working to create the order! I found this by checking the scope returned when creating the token.